# My app didn't support devices with 420dpi, 560dpi

Tags: android, samsung-galaxy, screen-density

My app didn't support devices with 260dpi, 420dpi, 560dpi.. screen density. Actually all devices except 160dpi,240dpi,320dpi, 480dpi and 640dpi screen density were excluded, like Samsung Galaxy Note8,9,10.... On other devices, It works well.  I don't know why. Please, Help me to solve the problem..!
Here is my manifest setting.
supports-screens, and user-permission, user-features

```
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 29
```

```
android:resizeable="true"
android:anyDensity="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE "/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

<meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.1" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi"android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" android:required="false" />
```

Help me!

Comment: I'd suspect the max_aspect, as it does add a restruction to devices.  Also, your manifest is kind of weird-  why would you have any of those uses features?  You would use them to restrict your app to devices that had those features, you'd never use them with required=false.  Makes me wonder what else you may have in there without realizing it

Comment: In fact just about all of this is unnecessary, everything you did in the supportsscreens and uses-features is the default.

Comment: Thanks, max_aspect, I 'll try to delete the mas_aspect.